# Language detection URL domain on localhost

Tags: i18n-l10n

I built a website in German on al local drupal installation. Now, I try to add English as a second language. As language detection method I am using URL. Using the path prefix option everything works well but when I try to use the domain option it doesn't work.

The domain option is what I want to use when the website is finally online.

mywebsite is in German and en.mywebsite is in English.

On my localhost I access my site with localhost/drupal722. I tried to configure the English URL as localhost/en.drupal722 but this does not work.

I deleted the path prefixes of both languages. Regarding the German domain configuration I tried both, leaving blank and insert localhost/drupal722/.

Does somebody has an advice on how to get this working?

Comment: just out of curiosity but why do you want the languages on specific subdomains instead of using the url suffix /en and /de?

Comment: Well, mostly because I came along this Google page https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=de (it's in German but surely there's one in English as well). There's a table that shows advantages and disadvantages of each method an the subdomain method seems to be best for my case. For example, I'd like to use the geografical targting in Google's Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 1):

It is better that you configure a subdomain or even a complete domain. For example, `site1.localhost` and `site2.localhost` and that you change your apache or web server to point to the Drupal root folder. Even you can change your OS hosts and link to fake domains, for example, `site1.example.com` and `site2.example.com`.

For multi-domain and multi-language I would recommend these modules which work like a charm:

- [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)
- [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)

You can add new sites and in each site have one or more different languages. These would solve all your problems as it works very well and it is pretty good in configuring content served from a single installation to several different domains and languages.